# Handling Enter Key on Text Area using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, textarea

I have 5 text areas on a page and I would like a specific event to occur on hitting the enter key on the first text area and a different event on enter key of the other text areas. Can you please suggest on how this can be acheived.

```
<TextArea></TextArea>
<TextArea></TextArea>
<TextArea></TextArea>
<TextArea></TextArea>
<TextArea></TextArea>
```

when hitting the enter on 1st Text Area, `alert('Text Area 1 clicked');`

when hitting the enter on the other 4 Text Area, `alert ('Other Text Area's clicked');`

Can this be acheived using jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/26kN7/1/

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if (code == 13) {  // Enter keycode
     if($(this).hasClass("first")) {
        alert("first ta clicked");
     } else {
         alert("the other ta clicked");
     }
   }
});
```

in some versions of FFX pressing `<Tab>`, e.which isn't set (remains 0), but e.keyCode is (9).

you can also shorten this to

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e){
    if((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) { //Enter keycode
      if($(this).hasClass("first")) {
        alert("first ta clicked");
      } else {
        alert("the other ta clicked");
      }
    }
});
```

the other thing note is I like adding the class here than finding the first textarea is cos this is more generic solution and could cater to any of the textareas.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using:

```
$('textarea').keypress(
    function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if ($(this).index() == 0) {
                // code for first textarea;
            }
            else {
                // code for others
            }
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZpsKr/).

Comment: from http://api.jquery.com/event.which/: `event.which` normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It is recommended to watch `event.which` for keyboard key input.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`which` property of the jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to determine which key was pressed.

```
$('textarea').first().keypress(function (e)
{
    if (e.which === 13) alert('Text Area 1 enter key pressed');
}).nextAll().keypress(function (e)
{
    if (e.which === 13) alert('Other Text Area enter key pressed');
});
```

Comment: in some versions of FFX pressing `<Tab>`, e.which isn't set (remains 0), but e.keyCode is (9).

Comment: That seems like a jQuery bug, and is not the key we're interested in here anyway. jQuery claims to fully normalize the event object so you _shouldn't_ need to use anything other than `event.which`.