# Firefox Javascript URL redirect

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a mock version of censored google for history class. The user enters in a search term, and if the term is "censored" they will be taken to a censor page, otherwise they would go straight to the actual google page. However, in Firefox only, the search seems to not be redirecting to the google page while only the censor portion of the script works. I checked in Google Chrome, and it works fine. Any ideas?

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id = "search" name="search" size="85" onKeyUp="searchCensor()"/><br />
```

Javascript:

```
function searchCensor() 
{
    var keyTerms = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if(keyTerms == "censorship")
        window.location = "http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/history/censor.php";
    else if(window.event.keyCode == 13)
        window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+keyTerms;
}
```

website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/history/

Answer (score 3):

`window.event` is exclusive to Internet Explorer 8 and below.

Where are you calling this function? You should probably have it in a `onsubmit` event for the form, in which case you don't need that keyCode check.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146659/handling-enter-key-on-text-area-using-javascript) and I have try it's work

Edit onKeyUp to `onKeyUp="searchCensor(event)`

And Edit your function to

```
function searchCensor(e) {
    var keyTerms = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if (keyTerms == "censorship") {
        window.location = "http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/history/censor.php";
    }
    else {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code  == 13) window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + keyTerms;
    }
}
```